# Автор вопроса уползает вправо

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

В любом вопросе вопросе при шевелении мышкой в районе меток и ссылок с действиями блок с автором уползает вправо. Уползает неограниченно далеко пропорционально некоторым действиям. Возможно связано с доступностью inline-редактирования меток и отображением соответствующей ссылки на новой строке (которая, кстати, не работает).

In any [question](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/668236/178988) when I hover somewhere near tags and action links, block with author moves to the right. It moves on some event and can be moved infinitely if i continue to move the mouse there. Possibly it's related to tags-inline-editind with link placed on the new line (by the way, it's not working).

[image: Скриншот]

Скринвидео / Screenvideo: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/46Ma/EEzDDT3r7

Comment: М-м-м... Ничего такого не замечаю. Ничего не уползает. Юзаю Firefox.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, добавил видео.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, в хроме воспроизводится

Comment: @Qwertiy, ха, похоже починили :-) обнови страничку

Comment: @Grundy, ага, похоже на то.

Comment: Ох уж эти ползучие авторы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот дефект был также замечен в [User card senses danger when chasing tricky “edit tags”, runs for dear life](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296193) и быстро исправлен.

[Технические подробности](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296202) могут быть интересны веб-разработчикам.